Deploy React App in Docker with Jenkins (also in Docker)
I have a react application which I'm trying to deploy to Docker using Jenkins which is also in Docker.
Currently in my react application I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:
# Stage 1: Build
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and lock file
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy all project files
COPY . .

# Pass the mode argument to Vite's build process
ARG MODE=docker-prod
RUN npm run build:${MODE}

# Stage 2: Serve with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine-slim AS prod
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


and I have a docker-compose.yml file that that looks like this
name: prod
services:
  frontend-prod:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        MODE: prod
    env_file: 
      - .env.prod
    container_name: prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - prod-network
      - dev-network

networks:
  prod-network:
    external: true
  dev-network:
    external: true


When I run this locally in the project docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d it works, my application is dockerized.
But when I try and deploy using Jenkins I get a whole host of errors - I've tried multiple different scripts like but can't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure if it's because I have Jenkins running in a Docker too or not. I'm relatively new to this all so I don't know what I don't know...
here are some examples of my Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Deploy Docker Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Deploying the Docker container...'
                    sh 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            echo 'Application deployed successfully.'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Deployment failed.'
        }
    }
}


pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:20-alpine'
            reuseNode true
        }
    }

    environment {
        IMAGE_NAME = 'prod'
        MODE = 'docker-prod'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build Application') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Building the application using Node.js...'
                    sh '''
                    mkdir -p /home/node/app
                    cd /home/node/app
                    # Copy package.json and lock file
                    cp /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Client/package*.json .
                    # Install dependencies
                    npm install
                    # Copy project files
                    cp -r /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Client/* .
                    # Build the application with the specified mode
                    npm run build:${MODE}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build Docker Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Building Docker image...'
                    // Use a Dockerfile directly to build the final image
                    sh '''
                    docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER} \
                        --build-arg MODE=${MODE} \
                        -f Dockerfile.
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Docker Container') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Running the Docker container...'
                    sh '''
                    docker run -d --name ${IMAGE_NAME}_container \
                        -p 8080:3000 ${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Verify Deployment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Verifying the deployment...'
                    sh '''
                    docker ps | grep ${IMAGE_NAME}_container
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            echo 'Pipeline executed successfully!'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Pipeline failed!'
        }
    }
}


What goes wrong?  Can you tell if it's a problem with your Jenkins installation or with your pipeline code?  Jenkins has some built-in support for building images, does using this instead of sh 'docker ...' work any better?
